# Does anyone have detailed and accurate travelocity.com sample app instructions that work?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

The WSO2IS sample app instructions are less than accurate and there are some key details to the instructions are missing. Does anyone have a ***complete*** set of instructions that will actually produce a working example?

Also, it seems like **localhost** is coded everywhere, some guidance on how to add and update the service provider and identity provider that are on different hosts is important.

also, is the patch or service pack needed for this to run correctly?  That info is not in the documentation or blogs I've been reading from WSO2

Comment: Please mention which version of WSO2IS you need to run travelocity sample

Comment: I am running on 5.0; basic right now but I'm going to add in SP1 and the patch soon if that makes a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a post on configuring the sample for a tenant scenario[1](http://wso2howto.blogspot.com/2015/01/how-to-configure-identity-server-sso.html). You should be able to configure using this. Change the hostname of SAML.IdPUrl in WEB-INF/classes/travelocity.property to that of IS. Change Assertion Consumer URL at SP registration and on WEB-INF/classes/travelocity.property to that of SP(travelocit app).

[1](http://wso2howto.blogspot.com/2015/01/how-to-configure-identity-server-sso.html) - [how-to-configure-identity-server-sso](http://wso2howto.blogspot.com/2015/01/how-to-configure-identity-server-sso.html)